# Retry on bpel INVOKE activity if backend service returns FAIL

Tags: wso2, bpel, wso2-business-process, oasis

I am trying to implement a scenario in which I have to invoke a third party soap service from `BPEL invoke activity`. If backend service returns "`SUCCESS`" then continue the sequence else if service returns "`FAIL`" then retry on invoke activity until "`SUCCESS`" is returned. 
I am unable to implement this scenario. Can any BPEL expert help me out?

Comment: Hi, IMO you should delegate this kind os logic to an integration layer.In practical terms, this means that your process logic which runs in the BPEL engine should not call directly an end point, but should instead route all calls to an ESB, where you can handle this kind of scenario easily (eg: use a "retry endpoint")

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late answer. You can just use a loop and check for the response and retry.

Comment: Could you perhaps add some example code to further your answer? It makes it easier for future users to see the code you suggested in the context provided.